# Why is my KO bindings need parentheses?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, breeze, durandal

I'm developing a website using Durandal/Knockout/Breeze/WebApi with MVC4 as the back end.
I'm querying my api via breeze like so:

```
var getCategories = function() {
    var query =
        entityQuery
            .from('Categories')
            .orderBy('Order');

    return manager.executeQuery(query);
};
```

Then, on my view model:

```
function initCategories() {
        service.getCategories()
               .then(querySuccess)
               .fail(queryFail);

        function querySuccess(data) {               
            vm.categories(data.results);
        };
```

where vm is my bounded view model and categories is of *observableArray* of course.

Finally, my view has:

```
<!-- ko foreach: categories -->

<div class="list_images">
    <a data-bind="attr: { href: '#search/' + queryString() }" class="hover-shadow">
        <img data-bind="attr: { src: image(), alt: name() }" width="240" height="180">
        <h5 data-bind="text: name()"></h5>
    </a>
</div>

<!-- /ko -->
```

Here's the screenshot of what data.results contains:

[image: Debugging info]

It works fine, except for the need of using the parentheses.
With 'normal' viewmodels I don't need parentheses in the view bindings.
**I can't figure out why it happens only with breeze objects (Entities).**

**Edit**
After further investigation I noticed that my entities are of type ***proto._setCtor.proto*** instead of just an Object. Why's that?
Even if I use the breeze manager to create a new entity - this is the object I get back :(
 What's wrong here?

Comment: What is the question?  I dont quite understand what problem you are having

Comment: @PW Kad - I've sharpened my question.
I'm just asking why do I need those parentheses in this case whereas in all other cases the binding declarations works as normal.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer. This is a confession that I'm mystified. *I can't duplicate the problem you describe.*

I understand exactly what you are asking. I agree that you should not have to use the parentheses. You should be able to write:

```
<h5 data-bind="text: name"></h5>
```

and not have to write:

```
<h5 data-bind="text: name()"></h5>
```

I downloaded the "Todo-Knockout" sample from Breeze. After confirming that it worked, I started changing it to look more like your binding example. I continued to work.

You can follow along with me, step-by-step, confirming that everything works as expected after each step.

- Switched to the comment form of repeater: `<!-- ko foreach: items -->`
- Replaced the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags with `div` container.
- Switched to the debug version of KO (that's what you're using)
- Updated to the latest KO (*knockout-3.1.0.debug.js*)

In the end, my revised markup looks like this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: items -->
<div>
    <div data-bind="visible: !isEditing()">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsDone" />
        <label data-bind="text: Description, click: $parent.editBegin, css: { done: IsDone, archived: IsArchived }"></label>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.deleteItem">X</a> 
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: isEditing">
        <form data-bind="event: { submit: $parent.editEnd }">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: Description, hasfocus: isEditing" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

When I break in the **Chrome Developer Tools** where the results are returned from the server and display `data.results` in the console, I get this:

```
[proto._setCtor.proto
    CreatedAt: function dependentObservable() {
    Description: function dependentObservable() {
    Id: function dependentObservable() {
    IsArchived: function dependentObservable() {
    IsDone: function dependentObservable() {
    entityAspect: ctor
    isEditing: function observable() {
    __proto__: Object

, proto._setCtor.proto, proto._setCtor.proto]
```

I'm not seeing any significant differences from your example. Do you?

What happens when you do the same thing with the same "Todo-Knockout" sample on your machine?

What browser are you using? Do you see the same misbehavior in Chrome?

Comment: Thanks, I was using the To-Do sample project to learn breeze and returned to it now to compare to your results:
The project is running fine.
But I'm having different console output than yours:
It's not dependentObservable but this: function h(){if(0<arguments.length)return"function"===typeof u?u.apply(d,arguments):i(Error("Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.")),this;m||g();b.r.Va(h);return k}
B: function (){z()}

Comment: @graumanoz This is *most likely* because you are using a minified version of Knockout.

Comment: Exactly, @PW Kad. If you switch to *knockout....debug.js*, you'll see the `dependentObservable`.

Comment: @PW Kad - Thanks for your help. I realized that something's wrong with my scripts versions and/or debug/release types, but couldn't find the way for it to work. So... I've started with a fresh MVC4 project and installed durandal/ko/breeze again and added all my existing project files and finally everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Breeze serializes all of the properties of your entity into ko.computeds under the covers.  It uses this to intercept changes to the properties and notify all the other places your property is used.  That being said you should only have to use parans in places where you are using conditional bindings (such as when you are combining a property with some string to make a longer string.  Where ever you are just binding to a standard ko binding handler you should not need it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I understand what Breeze do for me and my screenshot shows it as well. But if I drop the parentheses it just spit out the observable code to the screen, as if it is just a regular function and not a computed observable!

Comment: Only where you are combining the value of an observable with a string or something else conditional.  If you do it for example in your binding without anything else (CSS for example in your case) it just works.  Its because you are combining the value with something

Comment: Yes I get it. Believe me I know what observables are. You can see that queryString should be used with parentheses, and it does. The rest of them can be omitted, but when I do that it breaks. Can you think of a reason why in my case they aren't work as expected? My suspect is somehow Breeze. I may be missing something with it.

Comment: You don't have to, there must be something else breaking.  It's as simple as that, create a fiddle and if there is something else going on I can help you with it