# Durandal observablearray binding issue using databind-foreach

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, single-page-application, observable

I have just started to learn Durandal and ran into a problem with a binding issue with the observablearray.

I can confirm that there is data in the array because I can manually pop the data out render it. However when I try to list out the data using a foreach databind the data is not being rendered.

Can anyone help? I am not sure why the rendering via databind-foreach is failing.... Thank you in advance.

Here is the code for the view:

```
<section class="view">
<header>
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-force-refresh pull-right" 
        data-bind="click: refresh"><i class="icon-refresh"></i> Refresh</button>
    <h3 class="page-title" data-bind="text: title"></h3>
    <div class="article-counter">
        <address data-bind="text: speakers().length"></address>
        <address>found</address>            
    </div>


</header>
<!--Manual Pop to confirm we have data!-->
<section>
    <article class="article-container-full-width">
        <div>
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: speakers().pop().imageName() }" class="img-polaroid"/>
            <address data-bind="text: speakers().pop().firstName()"></address>
            <address data-bind="text: speakers().pop().lastName()"></address>
        </div>    
    </article>
</section>
<!--data bind for each, this is not working!-->
<section data-bind="foreach: speakers" class="view-list">
    <article class="article-container-full-width">
        <div>
            <img data-bind="attr: {src: imageName}" class="img-polaroid"/>
            <address data-bind="text: firstName"></address>
            <address data-bind="text: lastName"></address>
        </div>    
    </article>
</section>
```

Here is the code for the viewmodel:

```
define(['dataservice'], function (dataservice) {

var speakers = ko.observableArray();
var initialized = false;

var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    speakers: speakers,
    title: 'Speakers',
    refresh: refresh,
};

return vm;

function activate() {
    if(initialized) {return;}
    initialized = true;

    return refresh();
}

function refresh() {

    return dataservice.getSpeakersPartials(speakers);
}
```

});

Code for the Dataservice:

```
define(['logger', 'durandal/system', 'model'],
function (logger, system, model) {

var getSpeakersPartials = function(speakersObservable) {
    // reset the observable
    speakersObservable([]);

    // set ajax call
    var options = {
        url: '/api/speakers',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'
    };

    // make call
    return $.ajax(options)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);

    // handle the ajax callback
    function querySucceeded(data) {
        var speakers = [];
        data.sort(sortSpeakers);
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            var item = data[i];
            var speaker = new model.SpeakerPartial(item);
            speakers.push(speaker);
        }
        speakersObservable(speakers);
        log('Retrieved speaker partials from remote data source',
            speakers,
            true);
    }

};

var dataservice = {
    getSpeakersPartials: getSpeakersPartials
};
return dataservice;

//#region Internal methods
function sortSpeakers(s1, s2) {
    return(s1.firstName + s1.lastName > s2.firstName + s2.lastName)
        ? 1 : -1;
}


function queryFailed(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    var msg = 'Error getting data. ' + textStatus;
    logger.log(msg,
        jqXHR,
        system.getModuleId(dataservice),
        true);
}

function log(msg, data, showToast) {
    logger.log(msg,
        data,
        system.getModuleId(dataservice),
        showToast);
}
//#endregion
```

});

Comment: Are you using breeze? Then try adding parenthesis like in the working example and see if that works in the foreach block. There's a recent thread about a similar behavior http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447890/why-is-my-ko-bindings-need-parentheses, but so far no final answer.

Comment: what is the value of speakers().length that you're outputting? And what is logged by the logger in the dataservice when the data is retrieved?

Comment: @RainerAtSpirit, to my knowledge I am not using breeze, however at this point I am willing to try anything.

Comment: @Hans, vale of speakers().length is returning a value. It returns an integer value of 6. The only think I log is if it succeeds in retrieving data from the controller.

Comment: You also log the content of the speakers array in your GetSpeakersPartials method (success callback of the ajax call). I was wondering if you see an array with 6 items being logged there. Also, are there any binding errors in the console? Could you perhaps make a Fiddle? I can't spot anything wrong just by looking at the code.

Comment: @Hans, I do see an array with 6 items. I get the following from the console:
Debug:Enabled system.js:73
Application:Starting system.js:73
Application:Started system.js:73
[shell]  CodeCaper JumpStart Loaded! system.js:75
Binding shell 
Object {activate: function, __moduleId__: "shell"}
 system.js:75
[dataservice]  Retrieved speaker partials from remote data source 
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
length: 6
__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: Make sure that each objects properties in the array are observable.  The observablearray will give you loop, but if the elements in the array are not observable it won't show data.

Comment: @William, each property seems to be observable. Here is what I see from one of the objects in the console:

firstName: function observable() {
fullName: function dependentObservable() {
id: function observable() {
imageName: function dependentObservable() {
imageSource: function observable() {
lastName: function observable() {
__proto__: Object

Comment: If the data is all there and observable then it has to be knockout syntax error.  Knockout stops working from the error down.  Try taking out data-bind's and adding them one at a time to make sure they work.

Comment: I'm also not sure how speakers gets the data, it looks like its pushed to the refresh property in the VM.

Comment: @William, speakers is populated in the dataservice.js.  It makes an ajax get call to the controller and if that call is successful it executes the querySucceeded() to map the data to a speaker model.

Comment: I honestly can't find any reason why this is not working. No errors, the data is in your observables, and they are indeed all observables... can you try to reproduce this in a Fiddle?

Comment: I did a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/cimunope/2/edit?html,js,output) using only knockout and it works as expected, though I wouldn't use `pop()` to see if you have data. Use index notation. What does `new model.SpeakerPartial()` do?